# Is there a typesafe way to express 'related to property name xy on object Bar of this class' in a property attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, type-safety

Consider the following classes

```
public class Lorem 
{
    public double LoremsDouble { get; set; }        
}


public class Ipsum
{
    public Lorem IpsumsLorem { get; set; }

    public Dolor IpsumsDolor { get; set; }
}
```

No, as metadata to the property `IpsumsDolor`, I would like to have an attribute, which says: The property `IpsumsDolor` has a relation to `LoremsDouble` on `IpsumsLorem`. I know, this sounds like there is something wrong in my concept, but it isn't I swear!

I could do this by having string properties on my attribute, for example `string RelatedObject` and `string PropertyName` and use it via reflection, however I absolutely hate strings, unfortunately.

**SIDENOTE**

Coming from WPF and XAML, where property notifications are usually fired via strings, for example

```
RaisePropertyChanged("LoremsDouble");
```

I am using expressions to make this typesafe:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => LoremsDouble);
```

where the argument is a `Expression<Func<T>>`, and I translate this back into a string at the end, where there is nothing more to go wrong, like this:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression) propertyExpression.Body;
    var propertyName = body.Member.Name;
    ...
}
```

**END OF SIDENOTE**

Ok, now I wish, I could do the following

```
public class Ipsum
{
    public Lorem IpsumsLorem { get; set; }

    [RelatedProperty(() => IpsumsLorem.LoremsDouble)]
    public Dolor IpsumsDolor { get; set; }
}
```

but I can't, obviously, for (a) there's no object `IpsumsLorem` when instantiating the attribute and (b) an expression is not a valid attribute parameter.

**Do you have any good ideas to achieve relating the one property to a property on the other property's value in a typesafe way?**

Comment: That's why I ended up into the conclusion that it's necessary to "flatten" an object graph in order to expose it to a WPF UI. That's what ViewModels are for, you know.

Comment: @HighCore: I've got lots of ViewModels which flatten a lot of stuff. The reason for doing this is not UI related. The main idea is automatizing the property initialization, to give you the short version...